# Binding Lists in Kivy Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, listview, kivy, kivy-language

I am new to Kivy- Python and I need to create a list of items having an update and delete functionalities that get updated according to the list received from an API, just like we bind a ListView in Xaml. Is there any way to achieve it in Kivy?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example (of course no coding example) with some dummy data and the actions you want to achieve? Do you have problems with the building up the gui or just with the magic in the background, when you for example hit a button? I basically think it should be no problem but it is easier to explain when I fully get what you want to achieve.

Comment: Okay, so when a page loads an azure web service would be called and the list would be populated with names of the file. The list item would have options to download and delete that file. I want to know how to achieve it. I was talking about how to make a GUI for it but if you can help me with some background magic that would be a cherry on the cake :) Thank you!

Comment: @MisterNox any update?